# How to vertically and horizontally center a minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, minipage

1. I tried centering horizontally using the "adjustwidth" environment, but unfortunately, it's not very accurate. Also my captions are not centered under my figures anymore.
2. I have no idea how to use the area above my minipage. I tried using vspace, but I can't seem to move the minipage upwards.

Following image illustrates my issue:

[image: the problem]

Following piece of code (MWE) shows what I tried to do:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openright]{book} %oneside option
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

%PACKAGES
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{psfrag} %laprint
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdf,usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage[small,bf,hang]{caption}
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\small\itshape}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{n}{,}{,}     % Numerical system
\usepackage{listings}

%LAYOUT
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\setlength{\textheight}{237mm} %A4 - 297
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm} %A4 - 210
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.54cm} %A4
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} %A4
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.46cm}  %A4 Centers text.
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.54cm} %A4

%
%Left margin 30 mm, right margin 20 mm, top margin 20 mm, bottom     margin 20 mm.
%2,54

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% with this we ensure that the chapter and section
% headings are in lowercase.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer


\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}

\parskip 6pt           % sets spacing between paragraphs
\parindent 0pt       % sets leading space for paragraphs 

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\newenvironment{remark}[1][Remark]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\newcommand{\vectornorm}[1]{\|#1\|}

%Locally remove natural indent of itemize
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Reflex_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsEncoding.eps} 
        \caption{Reflex: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder} 
        \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_2a} 
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Reflex_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsDecoding.eps} 
        \caption{Reflex: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
        \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_2b}  
    \end{minipage}}%

    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{%       
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Lena_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsEncoding.eps} 
        \caption{Lena: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder} 
        \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_3a} 
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Lena_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsDecoding.eps} 
        \caption{Lena: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder} 
        \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_3b} 
    \end{minipage}}%

    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Fruits_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsEncoding.eps} 
        \caption{Fruits: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder} 
        \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_4a} 
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Fruits_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsDecoding.eps}
        \centering 
        \caption{Fruits: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
        \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_4b}  
    \end{minipage}}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As your minipages are bigger than half of the page, they will need some more place on both sides of the text. Just put every two minipages in a `\makebox` for this. (Not my recommendation. Try to fit everything in your margins as this will look more consistent over your whole report.)

For vertical centring, just use the `[p]` specifier of your `figure`. If you use [t] instead or none at all, it will be flushed to the top if followed by text. No need for `\vspace`.

Load `caption` in order to get better spacing between captions and following images.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{changepage} % not needed any more
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Reflex_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsEncoding.eps} 
            \caption{Reflex: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder} 
            \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_2a} 
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Reflex_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsDecoding.eps} 
            \caption{Reflex: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
            \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_2b}  
        \end{minipage}}%

        \makebox[\textwidth][c]{%       
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Lena_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsEncoding.eps} 
            \caption{Lena: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder} 
            \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_3a} 
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Lena_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsDecoding.eps} 
            \caption{Lena: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder} 
            \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_3b} 
        \end{minipage}}%

        \makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Fruits_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsEncoding.eps} 
            \caption{Fruits: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder} 
            \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_4a} 
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.565\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{plots/Fruits_128_Plot_xRemovals_yCPUsecondsDecoding.eps}
            \centering 
            \caption{Fruits: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
            \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_4b}  
        \end{minipage}}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @LaRiFaRi, thanks for your quick response. I editted my original post and created a minimal working example. Unfortunately, it's still not working.

Comment: @MoGuL This is far away from minimal. Please reduce. E.g. I can't find `luximono`. "It's still not working" is nothing, I can work with. What is not working? What are you expecting to get? What have you tried? Reduce your code until you see the problematic lines of code.

Comment: I see your point, I will modify! Well I just get the exact same outcome, that's what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibilities is to put pictures in table instead use `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{showframe} % just for demo
\usepackage{tabularx} % added package
    \usepackage{caption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}% reduce space between columns in table
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
\includegraphics[width=1\hsize]{example-image}\newline
\caption{Reflex: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder}
\label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_2a}
&
    \includegraphics[width=1\hsize]{example-image}\newline
    \caption{Reflex: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_2b}
            \\
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\newline
\caption{Lena: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder}
\label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_3a}
&
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\newline
    \caption{Lena: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_3b}
            \\
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\newline
\caption{Fruits: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder}
\label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_4a}
&   
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}\newline
    \caption{Fruits: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_4b}
        \end{tabularx}%
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

This solution require to load package `tabularx`, however benefits is more simple and concise code. Results is similar as show LaRiFari in his answer:

[image]

**Edit:**
The widths of images is determined with `[width=\hsize]` and limited with space in cells. For enlarge this spaces reduce `tabcolsep` and eliminate it on  beginning and end of table with `@{}` (see modified code).

Further reducing vertical white space with preserved aspect ratio of images is only possible with locally enlarged text width with use of `\usepackage{changepage}`. I do not know, if this can came to account.

Comment: Hi @Zarko, thanks for your response! This is indeed a bit closer to what I aim for. The problem is that I still have a lot of white space around my images. I would like to make them as big as possible, so that they fill they entire page, both vertically and horizontally. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can totally get rid of the figure environment and have full control, but you will be also totally responsible for the final output. Here is an implementation with the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package that will enable you of using the largest possible space horizontally and vertically. `tabularx` will still be very useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demo
\usepackage{tabularx} % added package
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}% reduce space between columns in table
\newcommand{\HT}{4.88cm}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=1\hsize,height=\HT]{example-image-A}\newline
    \captionof{figure}{Reflex: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_2a}
&
    \includegraphics[width=1\hsize,height=\HT]{example-image-B}\newline
    \captionof{figure}{Reflex: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_2b}
            \\
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=\HT]{example-image-C}\newline
    \captionof{figure}{Lena: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_3a}
&
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=\HT]{example-image-A}\newline
    \captionof{figure}{Lena: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_3b}
            \\
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=\HT]{example-image-B}\newline
    \captionof{figure}{Fruits: $128 \times 128$ - Encoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_4a}
&   
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=\HT]{example-image-C}\newline
    \captionof{figure}{Fruits: $128 \times 128$ - Decoder}
    \label{plot:encoding_decoding_cpu_time_4b}
\end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

[image]